# Windows phone 7 reaction on push

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

I want to send a push notification to a WP7 Device, and I want the Phone to react immediately. (App ist not running when push is coming in -> some code i wrote will be executed)

I know there are 3 Types of notifications, and if I understand them correctly, Raw doesnt help at all, because it will only work, if the app is running. Tile and Toast are just showing the user that there is something going on, but i wont be able to execute code directly. After all, the user has to tap somewhere to start the app.

So do I understand this correctly? (which means there is no way to do what i want to be done? context: mdm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You understood correctly.

Just to elaborate a bit for others who might be wondering: with toast notification user would be able launch the application by tapping on the Toast. Tile notification would update the tile with new data and user would tap on the Tile. Unlike tile notification, toast notification would come to the attention of the user even through a lock screen as the Toast appears at a very high level of the visual composition.